# Program not crashing when run from Makefile

Tags: makefile, segmentation-fault

I have a particular executable (let's call it `bin`) which crashes with a segfault when run normally with `./bin`, but if I create this Makefile:

```
all: 
./bin
```

and I do `make`, the executable runs without error and terminates correctly. How is this even possible?

Comment: Undefined behavior springs to mind.

Comment: Does not really seem so... it crashes every time outside the Makefile... I can see the segfault with gdb outside the Makefile, but when I do `gdb ./bin` inside it, it doesn't happen

Comment: So you have access to the source code. Can you prepare a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org/)? If that's a big job, you should check the shells first-- verify that you are using the same shell as Make, in case `bin` relies on it somehow. (You can put `$(info shell is $(SHELL))` in the makefile, and something like `echo $SHELL` on your command line.)

Comment: Yes I wrote it, but I already solved the problem... it was due to the limited stack size, since I was doing a lot of recursive calls. Is it possible that in the Makefile environment an higher limit is defined by default?

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what version of make you're using, but older versions of GNU make had a bug where make set its own stack size to "unlimited" then didn't set it back to the default value when running programs.  Newer versions of GNU make fix that bug so that programs are run with the default stack size.

See https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=22010